# Rename a foreign key constraint in ManyToMany

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

**spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.1**

**spring-boot-starter-data-jpa**

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "clients__semantics_permissions",               
    joinColumns = {
       @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "client_fk"))
    }
)
private Set<LevelTwoBase> semantics_level_two_base = new HashSet<LevelTwoBase>();
```

This results in:

```
# \d clients__semantics_permissions
Table "public.clients__semantics_permissions"
               Column            |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
    -----------------------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
     client_id                   | integer |           | not null | 
     semantics_level_two_base_id | integer |           | not null |
```

```
Indexes:
   "clients__semantics_permissions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY,
   btree (client_id, semantics_level_two_base_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
   "fk5nepw5pnbbeewptg0a3tft563" FOREIGN KEY (semantics_level_two_base_id) REFERENCES semantics__level_two_base(id)
   "semantics_fk" FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES clients__branch(id)
```

I don't know how to rename the foreign key for `semantics_level_two_base_id`. In other words I just don't like that `fk5nepw5pnbbeewptg0a3tft563`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `inverseForeignKey`:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)                                                                         
@JoinTable(name = "clients__semantics_permissions",                                                         
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "client_fk")) }, 
           inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "<the name you like>"))                                    
private Set<LevelTwoBase> semantics_level_two_base = new HashSet<LevelTwoBase>();
```

**Hibernate-Output for creating the schema:** (using *level_two_base_fk* as name)

```
Hibernate: create table clients__semantics_permissions (client_id int8 not null, semantics_level_two_base_id int8 not null, primary key (client_id, semantics_level_two_base_id))
Hibernate: create table foo (id int8 not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table level_two_base (id int8 not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table clients__semantics_permissions add constraint level_two_base_fk foreign key (semantics_level_two_base_id) references level_two_base
Hibernate: alter table clients__semantics_permissions add constraint client_fk foreign key (client_id) references foo
```